# Populating Select Options .. angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate an array that will be used to generate select options.

Basically for each button when first pressed it should add a row, when the button is pressed again it should add to the dropdown list another number. For instance if tile>living room is pressed 3 times you should have a row in the table with  td - tile living room /td td - select options 1 ,2 3> /td

Right now the buttons add the row but I cannot figure out how to add to the drop down lists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LeEzZVLCgNwTnqjdMczF?p=preview

Comment: What did console.log and the chrome debugging tools say when you asked them?

Comment: I had it peppered with logs and everything seems to work fine for adding rows to the table, this is more of a question of how to write the code for that portion of the program. I need advice on how to structure the code for the drop down select boxes. Thanks!